# How to create an abstractbook (collection of abstracts) including affiliations

Tags: abstract, authblk

I need to create an abstractbook, which is the collection
of about 20 abstracts. Each abstract should be placed on
a single page and each abstract comes with its title and
a single or multiple authors with their affiliations.
The abstractbook should include a TOC including all titles
and corresponding authors.

I am not yet sure what is the best Latex class for such a
task and how use affiliations for the single abstracts (as
I can't use \maketitle, as I have many abstracts).

Here a small example with just two abstracts:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Default is 15pt.

\begin{document}

{\centering \section*{This is a test title of an abstract}}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
First Author1, Second Author2\\
1Ministry of Silly Walks\\
2Institute of Everything Important\\
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\blindtext[3]

\pagebreak

{\centering \section*{This is a second abstract}}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
First Author1\\
1Ministry of Tomatoes\\
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

What are the best format settings, or has anyone else already created a collection of abstracts? How can a TOC with titles and authors be created?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this answer as a starting point.

First of all, the package `tocloft` allows us to create a "List of Abstracts"

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listabstractname}{List of Abstracts}
\newlistof[section]{abstracts}{abs}{\listabstractname}
```

Then we define our own environment `abstracts` which takes the title as argument

```
\newenvironment{abstracts}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{abstracts}%
\small%
\begin{center}%
  \textbf{#1}%
\end{center}%
\quotation%
\addcontentsline{abs}{abstracts}{#1}%
}{%
\endquotation%
\clearpage%
}
```

Finally, we create a new command `\abstractauthor` to print the author(s) in the document and add them to the "List of Abstracts"

```
\newcommand\abstractauthor[1]{\authortoabs{#1}\printabstractauthor{#1}}

\newcommand{\printabstractauthor}[1]{%
{\noindent\centering\scshape#1\par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}%
}
\newcommand{\authortoabs}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{abs}{%
    \protect\contentsline{section}{\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}%
  \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip5pt}%
}
```

To show the list you have then to call the command

```
\listofabstracts
```

and the `abstracts` environment should be something like

```
\begin{abstracts}{This is a test title of an abstract}
\abstractauthor{First Author, Second Author}
abstract contents
\end{abstracts}
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to add affiliations to authors. You can modify my code to achieve this....

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Default is 15pt.

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listabstractname}{List of Abstracts}
\newlistof[section]{abstracts}{abs}{\listabstractname}

\newenvironment{abstracts}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{abstracts}%
\small%
\begin{center}%
  \textbf{#1}%
\end{center}%
\quotation%
\addcontentsline{abs}{abstracts}{#1}%
}{%
\endquotation%
\clearpage%
}

\newcommand\abstractauthor[1]{\authortoabs{#1}\printabstractauthor{#1}}

\newcommand{\printabstractauthor}[1]{%
{\noindent\centering\scshape#1\par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}%
}
\newcommand{\authortoabs}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{abs}{%
    \protect\contentsline{section}{\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}%
  \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\listofabstracts
\clearpage

\begin{abstracts}{This is a test title of an abstract}
\abstractauthor{First Author, Second Author}
\blindtext[3]
\end{abstracts}

\begin{abstracts}{This is a second abstract}
\abstractauthor{First Author}
\blindtext[3]
\end{abstracts}

\end{document}
```

Output (List of Abstracts)

[image]

Output (an abstract)

[image]