# How to modify this code to write affiliation of the authors?

Tags: abstract, affiliation

I have been succesfully created a document of abstracts for an upcoming conferences based on this code which is available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218389/how-to-create-an-abstractbook-collection-of-abstracts-including-affiliations?rq=1) but could anyone tell me what should I modify to produce authors affiliation?  Many Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Default is 15pt.

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listabstractname}{List of Abstracts}
\newlistof[section]{abstracts}{abs}{\listabstractname}

\newenvironment{abstracts}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{abstracts}%
\small%
\begin{center}%
  \textbf{#1}%
\end{center}%
\quotation%
\addcontentsline{abs}{abstracts}{#1}%
}{%
\endquotation%
\clearpage%
}

\newcommand\abstractauthor[1]{\authortoabs{#1}\printabstractauthor{#1}}

\newcommand{\printabstractauthor}[1]{%
{\noindent\centering\scshape#1\par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}%
}
\newcommand{\authortoabs}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{abs}{%
    \protect\contentsline{section}{\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}%
  \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\listofabstracts
\clearpage

\begin{abstracts}{This is a test title of an abstract}
\abstractauthor{First Author, Second Author}
\blindtext[3]
\end{abstracts}

\begin{abstracts}{This is a second abstract}
\abstractauthor{First Author}
\blindtext[3]
\end{abstracts}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple approach.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Default is 15pt.

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listabstractname}{List of Abstracts}
\newlistof[section]{abstracts}{abs}{\listabstractname}

%%************************************ added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{authornum}
\newcommand{\TA}{\stepcounter{authornum}\textsuperscript{\theauthornum}}

\newcounter{affilnum}
\newcommand{\TF}{\stepcounter{affilnum}\textsuperscript{\theaffilnum}}

\newcommand{\afillauthor}[1]{\par\medskip\noindent\hfill\TF#1\hfill}

\newcommand{\printabstract}[1]{\par\vspace*{2em}#1}
%%************************************

\newenvironment{abstracts}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{abstracts}%
    \setcounter{authornum}{0}\setcounter{affilnum}{0}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<   
    \small%
    \begin{center}%
        \textbf{#1}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation% 
    \addtocontents{abs}{\vskip2ex}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<  
    \addcontentsline{abs}{abstracts}{#1}%
}{%
    \endquotation%
    \clearpage%
}

\newcommand{\printabstractauthor}[1]{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    {\noindent\hfill\scshape#1\TA\hfill}
}%

\newcommand{\addauthortoToC}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \par\addtocontents{abs}{%
        \protect\contentsline{section}{\vskip-1.7\baselineskip\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}%
}


\begin{document}
    
    \listofabstracts
    \clearpage

    \begin{abstracts}{This is a test title of an abstract}
        \printabstractauthor{First Author}
        \printabstractauthor{Second Author}
        \addauthortoToC{First Author, Second Author}
        \afillauthor{University One}
        \afillauthor{University Two}
        \printabstract{\blindtext[3]}
    \end{abstracts}
    
    \begin{abstracts}{This is a second abstract}
        \printabstractauthor{First Author}
        \addauthortoToC{First Author}
        \afillauthor{University Three}
        \printabstract{\blindtext[3]}
    \end{abstracts}
    
    \begin{abstracts}{This is a third abstract}
        \printabstractauthor{First Author}
        \printabstractauthor{Second Author}
        \printabstractauthor{Third Author}
        \addauthortoToC{First Author, Second Author, Third Author}
        \afillauthor{University One}
        \afillauthor{University Two}
        \afillauthor{University Three}
        \printabstract{\blindtext[3]}
    \end{abstracts}
    
\end{document}
```